# Remove linearly increasing "count" columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with some columns representing counts for every timestep, I would like to automatically drop these, for example like the `df.dropna()` functionality, but something like `df.dropcounts()`.

Here is an example dataframe

```
array = [[0.0,1.6,2.7,12.0],[1.0,3.5,4.5,13.0],[2.0,6.5,8.6,14.0]]
pd.DataFrame(array)

     0    1    2     3
0  0.0  1.6  2.7  12.0
1  1.0  3.5  4.5  13.0
2  2.0  6.5  8.6  14.0
```

I would like to drop the first and last columns

Comment: Are they always going to increase with a factor of 1?

Comment: for the moment, yes (if it was adaptable for a defined value that could be nice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need:

```
val = 1
df = df.loc[:, df.diff().fillna(val).ne(val).any()]
print (df)
     1    2
0  1.6  2.7
1  3.5  4.5
2  6.5  8.6
```

**Explanation**:

First compare by [`DataFrame.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html):

```
print (df.diff())
     0    1    2    3
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  1.0  1.9  1.8  1.0
2  1.0  3.0  4.1  1.0
```

Replace `NaN`s:

```
print (df.diff().fillna(val))
     0    1    2    3
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  1.9  1.8  1.0
2  1.0  3.0  4.1  1.0
```

Compare if not equal by [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html):

```
print (df.diff().fillna(val).ne(val))
       0      1      2      3
0  False  False  False  False
1  False   True   True  False
2  False   True   True  False
```

And chck at least one `True` per column by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
print (df.diff().fillna(val).ne(val).any())
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `all`

```
d.loc[:,~d.diff().fillna(1).eq(1).all().values]
Out[295]: 
     1    2
0  1.6  2.7
1  3.5  4.5
2  6.5  8.6
```